# SteamVR SDK: HMD Camera Location is out of chaperone bounds, but the controllers aren't

Tags: unity-game-engine, virtual-reality, htc-vive

*Nothing's worse than setting up an SDK exactly the way the developers ask you to and having it not work... I'm posting this question to share an issue I found setting up a bare bones VR scene in Unity 2017.1.1*

**The Scene's contents**: CameraRig, SteamVR prefab, and a plane for the floor.

**The problem**: The SteamVR bounds are clearly displayed, and from the HMD's perspective I'm not within the bounds. Incidentally, my controllers *are* in bounds where they should be...

Answer (score 0):

If you look under 'Camera (eye)' in the inspector, you may see the camera's Depth attribute set to -1. Just set it to 0 and you should be golden.

The original settings, to my understanding, cause your camera to render a meter away from the intended HMD position.